# Simple Button Transparent Background on Xtragrid

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid, simplebutton

i want to add a simple button on the view caption section or the group panel section of the xtragrid (see attached images). The problem is that i can't find a way to make the button's background transparent. I've tried almost everything on the devexpress forums (disable default style, make it flat, ultraflat, no borders e.t.c) but nothing worked. The image has transparency (it's from devexpress's default images).

[image]

[image]

Code I've tried:

```
btn.LookAndFeel.Style = Flat;
btn.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
btn.Appearance.BackColor = Transparent;
btn.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.Transparent;
btn.BorderStyle = BorderStyles.NoBorder;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please post code that you have tried for better assistance.  As this question stands it's too broad and risks being closed.

Comment: thnx @ewitkows, i've updated the question, hope it's okay now.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I still can't find a solution to this.

Comment: Nope...probably can't be done. I just faked it with similar colors.